# My app just working fine in Nexus emulator but keeps crashing on the Pixel one

Tags: android

I have made a simple Timer app in Android, like whenever 10sec will be passed it will give a message **"DONE!!!"**.

in a `text view` (Planning to add a beep sound ) along with showing the `CountdownTimer` in another text view. But i noticed my app run perfectly fine on the nexus emulator and just crashed on the pixel emulator ,

Also it keeps crashing on my real Phone (Redmi note 4),

What could be the reason for this?

My code:

```
package com.example.pickachu.timerapp;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Time;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final TextView time=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Time);
        final TextView Status =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Status);


       new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                time.setText("SEC   :   "+String.valueOf(l/1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Status.setText("DONE!!!");
                time.setText("SEC  :  0");
            }

        }.start();
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/clock"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:context="com.example.pickachu.timerapp.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Time"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:paddingTop="12sp"
        android:text="@string/Time"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.369" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Status"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="11sp"
        android:text="@string/Status"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.567"
        tools:text="@string/Status" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat error message:

```
02-05 10:49:51.001 4637-4637/com.example.pickachu.timerapp     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.pickachu.timerapp, PID: 4637
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(128399328bytes) bitmap.
      at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
      at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
      at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:528)
      at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:17428)
      at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:17364)
      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17176)
      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17188)
      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:753)
      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2800)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2608)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2215)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/881pX.png)

Comment: please post stacktrace

Comment: could you post the crash logcat

Comment: please post logcat error report.

Comment: ok wait a second

Comment: please post your crash logs in your question.. then only we will be able to identify the problem.. Thanks :)

Comment: Logcat ScreenShot : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fguriH4aGvkpApfsQYRLgeUs8feZichR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, in the question itself.

Comment: Logcat Error Text : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-JxNRUUyx3RsiWBuhaNDGbgxXM1Ncxh3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit the question to add that. Don't link to necessary information offsite.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Cause your real phone has trouble to find the drawable images of the screen at runtime. Place your images to phone's resolution(drawable) folder. If you run your application through all the devices, you should add images to all resolution(drawable) folder. Place your drawable images to `drawable-xxhdpi` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess , There was some problem with the image that i was using . I just replaced the image and it worked fine. So now , can anyone Explain me what was the problem..

And how to fix these kinds of problems in the future. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your emulator might be having low cache size or RAM size. This won't happen in real life though.

Comment: That's not the case ...It has a good amount of ram and i even ran it on real device.

Comment: Oh! So are you facing the crash on Pixel (Real Device)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce Image Size..  It will work

Answer (score 0):

Try changing tools:text="@string/Status" into android:text="@string/Status" for textview "@+id/Status".

Answer (score 0):

Remove app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock" from imageview as you already set background to layout.